# tips on adding object from sheet's textfields to coredata

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to override the add: button my arraycontroller so that when a user presses add, a sheet appears by which they can input the values for the property of the new object to be added, and upon which the object will be added to the managedobjectcontext and the arraycontroller will refresh the table view in the first view with an update of the arrangedObjects

i've looked around and the only things i've found use document based applications that doesn't really work with how my app is set up right now, which already uses a lot of view switching via a managingViewController.

any help would be great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Display the sheet, create the object as configured by the user.

Then you could add it at the end through NSArrayController's `addObject` (programatically, not through IB).  "Select Inserted Objects" is an option here.  In that case, you're done.

If you want to add it at the beginning or somewhere else and you are using `sortDescriptors`, you can save it to the context, call NSArrayController's `rearrangeObjects` and then tell the array controller to select it with NSArrayController's `setSelectionIndex:`

With bindings, you shouldn't need to call `reloadData` on the tableView.